# jVectorMap region labels overlap

Tags: javascript, html, jvectormap

I've a world map with some highlighted countries, and only for these countries, I want to show the labels.

The issue is that if these countries are close to each other, the labels are overlapped and unreadable.

[image]

I know I can modify the position of the labels using the offset function, but these countries can be *activated* or *deactivated* automatically by a CMS, therefore I don't know in advance which one will be highlighted and if their labels will overlap.

here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var map = "world_mill_en",
      regions = {"AF":1,"BI":1,"CM":1,"CF":1,"CD":1,"HT":1,"HN":1,"IQ":1,"LS":1,"SY":1};
  $("#map").vectorMap({
    map: map,
    series: {
      regions: [{
        values: regions,
        attribute: "fill"
      }]
    },
    labels: {
      regions: {
        render: function(code){
          return regions[code] && jvm.Map.maps[map].paths[code].name;
        },
        offsets: function(code){
          return {
            'HT': [150, 70], //doesn't work??
            'HN': [0, 40]
          }[code.split('-')[1]];
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>jVectorMap Labels</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/jquery-jvectormap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    .jvectormap-region.jvectormap-element {
    font-size:9px;
      text-shadow: -1px -1px 3px #fff, 1px -1px 3px #fff, -1px 1px 3px #fff, 1px 1px 3px #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/jquery-jvectormap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/tests/assets/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So my question is: Is there a way to avoid region labels overlap? or an algorithm that I can implement to set the right offset for the labels?

Comment: You could change the x / y position of the label if its too close to another. However this could result in mislabeling small countries. Pain but you could also set each label position manually.